# How can logger.removeHandler(logger.handlers[0]) throw ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list?

Tags: python, django, list, logging

I'm trying to debug an exception in someone else's Python code, and I am not an expert in Python. The code tries to flush and remove all handlers on a standard Python Logger:

```
def restart_logging(logger_id):
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_id)
    while logger.handlers:
        handler = logger.handlers[0]
        handler.flush()
        logger.removeHandler(handler)
    init_logging(logger_id)
```

This raises an exception:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1208, in removeHandler
    self.handlers.remove(hdlr)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I've reviewed StackOverflow's other "x not in list" questions, and they all fit in these two categories:

- removing the same item more than once (usually because of doing `for x in list: list.remove(x)` rather than `while list: list.remove(list[0])`)
- remove an item that was never in the list

I don't see how either applies here.

Firstly, a while loop is used: while there are still handlers, take the first one (which succeeds or there'd be an `IndexError`), flush it, remove it. Even if that removed more than one entry in the list, it's a while loop testing if the list still has entries, not a for loop iterating over (potentially removed) objects.

Looking at the `logging` module source, it only calls `remove()` *once*, and it even *checks the handler is in the list* immediately before calling `remove()`:

```
def removeHandler(self, hdlr):
    """
    Remove the specified handler from this logger.
    """
    if hdlr in self.handlers:
        #hdlr.close()
        hdlr.acquire()
        try:
            self.handlers.remove(hdlr)
        finally:
            hdlr.release()
```

This code is executing as part of a Django web application. I could understand if it were, for example, a Java J2EE application, where two threads could be accessing the same list concurrently and there's no lock to make "get first item and remove it" an atomic operation, so both threads would see the same element in a list but only one would remove it and the other would fail because the thread removed the element between the first thread's "is this item in the list" and "remove this item from the list".

But, as far as I understand, Python has no concurrency, and uses a Global Interpreter Lock to stop more than one thing happening at once. So this shouldn't be possible.

So, I can't figure out why `list.remove(x): x not in list` is happening here, and I can't make a test case where it reliably happens. What could I do to further understand the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While individual operations may be atomic (along with operations such as `list.remove` as you may have noted, but this is **only** due to implementation details of CPython), `removeHandler` certainly is not. In the Python 2.6 implementation (which you have very helpfully posted), the context switch can happen after the `if` statement and before the lock acquisition (assuming that is what `hdlr.acquire()` does).  So if two threads called this function at the same time, it is guaranteed to cause an exception when one thread subsequently released its hold on GIL as the other runs through the entire thing to completion (original thread will continue from inside the if, handler is still pointing to the original one, which will acquire the IO lock, then tries to remove it from the list, causing an unwanted exception).

In Python 2.7, this has been fixed and the `removeHandler` method was changed to this:

```
    def removeHandler(self, hdlr):
        """
        Remove the specified handler from this logger.
        """
        _acquireLock()
        try:
            if hdlr in self.handlers:
                self.handlers.remove(hdlr)
        finally:
            _releaseLock()
```

Note how the lock is now acquired before the if statement.